# Can Hall's theorem be derived from Tutte–Berge formula?

Tags: graph-theory

Can [Hall's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_theorem#Graph_theoretic_formulation) be derived from [Tutte–Berge formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte%E2%80%93Berge_formula)?

Hall's theorem is for existence of X-saturated matching in a X,Y bipartite graph.

Tutte–Berge formula is for maximum size of a matching:

> The theorem states that the size of a maximum matching of a graph $G =
>  (V, E)$ equals
>
> $$\frac{1}{2} \min_{U\subseteq V} \left(|U|-\text{odd}(G-U)+|V|\right).$$
>
> where $odd(H)$ is the number of components in the graph H with an odd
>   number of vertices.

If apply Tutte–Berge formula to a X,Y bipartite graph which has a X-saturated matching, then since the maximum size of a matching is $|X|$, we should have

$$\frac{1}{2} \min_{U\subseteq V} \left(|U|-\text{odd}(G-U)+|V|\right) = |X|,$$

which is equivalent to that $U=X$ maximizes $odd(G-U) - |U|$, at which $odd(G-X) - |X| = |Y|$.

But this is nothing like Hall's condition: for any subset $W$ of $X$, $$ |W| \leq |N(W)|,$$ 
although I can vaguely and inexplicitly see that they are likely to be equivalent.

So I think Hall's theorem can be derived from Tutte-Berge formula?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1803729/29780